# How to fetch the phone number for the imessage extension created application

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessagefilter

I am trying to implement an iMessage Extension application, i want to fetch the number for whom i have selected the imessage to be created with the app i have created.

How to fetch the number whom I am sending this custom message. Any idea ? as I could not get much information from the Message Class referenced in the 'MSMessage' library file.

I can only access the UUID which is not what I want.

Thanks for any suggestions given.

Comment: In iOS its not possible , but along with iOS10 now developer can work with user Call log , but getting phone number , i dont think it is possible

Comment: Bro, have you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment it's not possible. It's more a question of privacy, Apple doesn't want dev to access private data like that. Maybe later Apple will allow it via a permission asked to the user (like they do for agenda/position etc).

Comment: Hope they come out with it soon , else no use of the iMessage extension than just to make stickers and not use the contact person information that application may need to process some business logic.

Comment: hum not sure about that, iMessage extension can be use for other things ;)